# CORREL Function only returns values of 0, 1, or -1 on varied dataset

Tags: vba, excel

I have a two 1x345 arrays with historical price and storage data.  While I can calculate the correlation coefficient manually for the entire arrays I want to calculate a number of correlation coefficients for different time offsets.  (Basically what is the coefficient if I lag one array 1 week, 2 weeks, etc.)  To achieve this I wrote a simple VBA script that (hopefully!) correlates a "lagged" B column against a static A column.  Currently however the macro is only returning values of 0, 1, or -1 which are obviously incorrect.

Any ideas on why the CORREL function is kicking out those rounded answers?

```
Sub cor()
    Dim i As Long, Astart As Long, Aend As Long
    Dim Bstart As Long, Bend As Long
    Dim cor As Long, offset As Long
    For i = 2 To 346
        offset = Cells(i, 3).Value
        Astart = 2
        Aend = 346 - offset
        Bstart = 2 + offset
        Bend = 346
        If Astart >= Aend Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Set arng = Range("A" & Astart & ":A" & Aend)
        Set brng = Range("B" & Bstart & ":B" & Bend)
        cor = WorksheetFunction.Correl(arng, brng)
        Cells(i, 4).Value = co
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you define `cor` as Long that's what will happen, since a Long can only hold a whole number. Try `As Double` instead..  Note you're using `co` to set the return value - that variable is not declared.

Comment: Sorry the 'co' is just a mistake from formatting into SO.  But duh...  Thank you, can't believe I overlooked that!

Comment: @TimWilliams that would have made a good answer.... why answer in comments?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - just a habit i need to get out of.  I tend to add a comment when the answer is just a typo or similar.  An answer would be better though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Long` is a 32-bit **Integer** type.

Depending on your precision needs you'll want to be using a `Single` or a `Double` instead, as [Tim Williams indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236168/vba-correl-function-only-returns-values-of-0-1-or-1-on-varied-dataset#comment65809692_39236168).